# OpenCV 3.0 building from source Visual Studio 2013 Problems

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to build opencv3.0 from source with cuda 6.5 support in visual studio 2013 in 32 bit ! following https://initialneil.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/opencv-2-4-9-cuda-6-5-visual-studio-2013/ . my GPU is Gefore 210 . I Know thats CUDA Compatible with compute capability 1.2. When i configure it with CMAKE it all goes fine!

**CMAKE OUTPUT!**

```
The system is: Windows - 6.1 - AMD64
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.31101.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18408]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 8/4/2015 12:59:49 AM.
Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\3.3.0\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdCXX.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdCXX.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdCXX.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj
  CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj -> D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\3.3.0\CompilerIdCXX\.\CompilerIdCXX.exe
PostBuildEvent:
  for %%i in (cl.exe) do @echo CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=%%~$PATH:i
  :VCEnd
  CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "Debug\CompilerIdCXX.tlog\CompilerIdCXX.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\3.3.0\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.95


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CompilerIdCXX.exe"

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj"

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/3.3.0/CompilerIdCXX/CompilerIdCXX.exe"

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler:  
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.31101.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18408]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 8/4/2015 12:59:51 AM.
Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\3.3.0\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "Debug\".
  Creating directory "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c
  CMakeCCompilerId.c
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdC.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdC.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdC.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCCompilerId.obj
  CompilerIdC.vcxproj -> D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\3.3.0\CompilerIdC\.\CompilerIdC.exe
PostBuildEvent:
  for %%i in (cl.exe) do @echo CMAKE_C_COMPILER=%%~$PATH:i
  :VCEnd
  CMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "Debug\CompilerIdC.tlog\CompilerIdC.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\3.3.0\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.63


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CompilerIdC.exe"

Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CompilerIdC.vcxproj"

The C compiler identification is MSVC, found in "D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/3.3.0/CompilerIdC/CompilerIdC.exe"

Determining if the CXX compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_19627.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.31101.0

[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18408]

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 8/4/2015 12:59:52 AM.

Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_19627.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTC_19627.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

  Creating directory "cmTC_19627.dir\Debug\cmTC_19627.tlog\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTC_19627.dir\Debug\cmTC_19627.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTC_19627.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_19627.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCXXCompiler.cxx

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTC_19627.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_19627.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCXXCompiler.cxx



  testCXXCompiler.cxx

Link:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_19627.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_19627.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_19627.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 /debug cmTC_19627.dir\Debug\testCXXCompiler.obj

  cmTC_19627.vcxproj -> D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_19627.exe

FinalizeBuildStatus:

  Deleting file "cmTC_19627.dir\Debug\cmTC_19627.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".

  Touching "cmTC_19627.dir\Debug\cmTC_19627.tlog\cmTC_19627.lastbuildstate".

Done Building Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_19627.vcxproj" (default targets).



Build succeeded.

    0 Warning(s)

    0 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.90



Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_9f8c9.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.31101.0

[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18408]

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 8/4/2015 12:59:53 AM.

Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_9f8c9.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTC_9f8c9.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "cmTC_9f8c9.dir\Debug\cmTC_9f8c9.tlog\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTC_9f8c9.dir\Debug\cmTC_9f8c9.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTC_9f8c9.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_9f8c9.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\share\cmake-3.3\Modules\CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp"

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTC_9f8c9.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_9f8c9.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\share\cmake-3.3\Modules\CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp"



  CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp

Link:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_9f8c9.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_9f8c9.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_9f8c9.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 /debug cmTC_9f8c9.dir\Debug\CMakeCXXCompilerABI.obj

  cmTC_9f8c9.vcxproj -> D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_9f8c9.exe

FinalizeBuildStatus:

  Deleting file "cmTC_9f8c9.dir\Debug\cmTC_9f8c9.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".

  Touching "cmTC_9f8c9.dir\Debug\cmTC_9f8c9.tlog\cmTC_9f8c9.lastbuildstate".

Done Building Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_9f8c9.vcxproj" (default targets).



Build succeeded.

    0 Warning(s)

    0 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.85





Detecting CXX [] compiler features compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_72ba9.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.31101.0

[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18408]

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 8/4/2015 12:59:55 AM.

Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_72ba9.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTC_72ba9.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

  Creating directory "cmTC_72ba9.dir\Debug\cmTC_72ba9.tlog\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTC_72ba9.dir\Debug\cmTC_72ba9.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTC_72ba9.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_72ba9.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\feature_tests.cxx

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTC_72ba9.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_72ba9.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\feature_tests.cxx



  feature_tests.cxx

Link:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_72ba9.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_72ba9.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_72ba9.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 /debug cmTC_72ba9.dir\Debug\feature_tests.obj

  cmTC_72ba9.vcxproj -> D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_72ba9.exe

FinalizeBuildStatus:

  Deleting file "cmTC_72ba9.dir\Debug\cmTC_72ba9.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".

  Touching "cmTC_72ba9.dir\Debug\cmTC_72ba9.tlog\cmTC_72ba9.lastbuildstate".

Done Building Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_72ba9.vcxproj" (default targets).



Build succeeded.

    0 Warning(s)

    0 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.86



    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_alias_templates
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_alignas
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_alignof
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_attributes
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_attribute_deprecated
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_auto_type
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_binary_literals
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_constexpr
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_contextual_conversions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_decltype
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_decltype_auto
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_default_function_template_args
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_defaulted_functions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_defaulted_move_initializers
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_delegating_constructors
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_deleted_functions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_digit_separators
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_enum_forward_declarations
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_explicit_conversions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_extended_friend_declarations
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_extern_templates
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_final
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_func_identifier
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_generalized_initializers
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_generic_lambdas
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_inheriting_constructors
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_inline_namespaces
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_lambdas
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_lambda_init_captures
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_local_type_template_args
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_long_long_type
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_noexcept
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_nonstatic_member_init
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_nullptr
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_override
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_range_for
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_raw_string_literals
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_reference_qualified_functions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_return_type_deduction
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_right_angle_brackets
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_rvalue_references
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_sizeof_member
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_static_assert
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_strong_enums
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_template_template_parameters
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_thread_local
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_trailing_return_types
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_unicode_literals
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_uniform_initialization
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_unrestricted_unions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:0cxx_user_literals
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_variadic_macros
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_variadic_templates
Determining if the C compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe" "cmTC_58b75.vcxproj" "/p:Configuration=Debug" "/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.31101.0

[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18408]

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



Build started 8/4/2015 12:59:56 AM.

Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_58b75.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).

PrepareForBuild:

  Creating directory "cmTC_58b75.dir\Debug\".

  Creating directory "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".

  Creating directory "cmTC_58b75.dir\Debug\cmTC_58b75.tlog\".

InitializeBuildStatus:

  Creating "cmTC_58b75.dir\Debug\cmTC_58b75.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.

ClCompile:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"cmTC_58b75.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_58b75.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c

  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.



  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"cmTC_58b75.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_58b75.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c



  testCCompiler.c

Link:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_58b75.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_58b75.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"D:/OpenCV/opencv/build_custom/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_58b75.lib" /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 /debug cmTC_58b75.dir\Debug\testCCompiler.obj

  cmTC_58b75.vcxproj -> D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_58b75.exe

FinalizeBuildStatus:

  Deleting file "cmTC_58b75.dir\Debug\cmTC_58b75.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".

  Touching "cmTC_58b75.dir\Debug\cmTC_58b75.tlog\cmTC_58b75.lastbuildstate".

Done Building Project "D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_58b75.vcxproj" (default targets).



Build succeeded.

    0 Warning(s)

    0 Error(s)



Time Elapsed 00:00:00.86
```

When i start building the generated Opencv.sln that gave me the following error. I started VS with Administrative Rights! Visual Studio Errors!

```
Error 3791  error : cannot unlink temp file C:/Users/zed_home/AppData/Local/Temp/ccB#.a04008  D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\modules\cudaarithm\CUSTOMBUILD  opencv_cudaarithm
Error 195 error : The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.  D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\modules\core\CUSTOMBUILD  opencv_core
Error 196 error : The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.  D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\modules\core\CUSTOMBUILD  opencv_core
Error 197 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_core300d.lib' D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\modules\imgproc\LINK  opencv_imgproc
Error 198 error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_core300d.lib' D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\modules\flann\LINK  opencv_flann
Error 3795  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_core300d.lib' D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\modules\ml\LINK opencv_ml
Error 3794  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib'  D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\modules\videoio\LINK  opencv_videoio
Error 3793  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_imgproc300d.lib'  D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\modules\imgcodecs\LINK  opencv_imgcodecs
Error 3796  error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_videoio300d.lib'  D:\OpenCV\opencv\build_custom\modules\highgui\LINK  opencv_highgui
Warning 14  warning : base class dllexport/dllimport specification differs from that of the derived class D:\OpenCV\opencv\sources\modules\core\include\opencv2\core.hpp  98  1 opencv_core
```

**CMAKE_OUT**

```
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Host:                        Windows 6.1 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.3.0
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 12 2013
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1800

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe  (ver 18.0.31101.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast  /wd4251 /wd4324 /MP2  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG  /Zi
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast  /wd4251 /wd4324 /MP2  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast    /MP2  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG  /Zi
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:SSE2 /Oi /fp:fast    /MP2  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:X86  /INCREMENTAL:NO  /debug
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:X86  /debug /INCREMENTAL 
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32 vfw32 cudart nppc nppi npps cufft
    3rdparty dependencies:       zlib libjpeg libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 hal cudev core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml video cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect ts features2d calib3d cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo stitching superres videostab python2
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python3 viz

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
    WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    GDAL:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    Video for Windows:           YES
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      codec:                     YES (ver 55.18.102)
      format:                    YES (ver 55.12.100)
      util:                      YES (ver 52.38.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 2.3.100)
      resample:                  NO
      gentoo-style:              YES
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            NO
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Intel PerC:                  NO

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     8.2.1 [8.2.1]
         at:                     D:/OpenCV/opencv/sources/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_win
    Use IPP Async:               NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use TBB:                     NO
    Use OpenMP:                  NO
    Use GCD                      NO
    Use Concurrency              YES
    Use C=:                      NO
    Use pthreads for parallel for:
                                 NO
    Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 6.5)
    Use OpenCL:                  YES

  NVIDIA CUDA
    Use CUFFT:                   YES
    Use CUBLAS:                  NO
    USE NVCUVID:                 NO
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             11 12 13 20 21 30 35
    NVIDIA PTX archs:            30
    Use fast math:               NO

  OpenCL:
    Version:                     dynamic
    Include path:                D:/OpenCV/opencv/sources/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMDFFT:                  NO
    Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Python27/python.exe (ver 2.7.8)
    Libraries:                   C:/Python27/libs/python27.lib (ver 2.7.8)
    numpy:                       C:/Python27/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.0)
    packages path:               C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 NO

  Python (for build):            C:/Python27/python.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/include C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/include/win32 C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:
    mex:                         NO

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     NO
    PlantUML:                    NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

  Install path:                  D:/OpenCV/opencv/buildCs/install

  cvconfig.h is in:              D:/OpenCV/opencv/buildCs
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
```

Comment: Looks like you are building `cudaarithm` without having built the OpenCV modules first.  Can you change your build default to solution and see if that helps?

Comment: Should i build WithoutCuda and see if errors are still there??

Comment: You can try that.  I assume that you have CUDA drivers installed.

Comment: Ok when i Build without CUDA support it worked and the Build was successful. But I want to build it with CUDA ! What Should i do??

Comment: Cool, did you make sure that the CUDA drivers are installed?  You need to download CUDA from Nvidia and install it before trying to build OpenCV with CUDA support.

Comment: i have cuda 6.5 installed ! Cmake Detects it too !  **CMAKE_OUTPUT** NVIDIA CUDA
    Use CUFFT:                   YES
    Use CUBLAS:                  NO
    USE NVCUVID:                 NO
    NVIDIA GPU arch:             11 12 13 20 21 30 35
    NVIDIA PTX archs:            30
    Use fast math:               NO
The GPU arch is 11 but the PTX arch is 30 ! is that a problem??

Comment: It is possible that some of your CUDA libraries/DLLs may not be in the `PATH` variable.  Can you check on that and try to rebuild?

Comment: There are CUDA_BIN_PATH , CUDA_INC_PATH,CUDA_LIB_PATH ,CUDA_PATH_V6.5 defined in env i previously installed 4.0 and 5.5 :/ is that a problem?? :/ i also have them as cuda_path_v4.0 and 5.5 :?

Comment: Not sure if the previous installations cause a conflict.  The other thing to check may be the project properties in Visual Studio and tune those.

Comment: I just Found that the Path was having 4.0 CUDA path i changed it to 6.5 now its building for the last 50 mins :/ Only one error shows up :/                              Error 1851 error : cannot unlink temp file C:/Users/zed_home/AppData/Local/Temp/ccBI#.a04144 D:\OpenCV\opencv\buildCs\modules\cudaarithm\CUSTOMBUILD opencv_cudaarithm
:/ 
it got stuck i think :/